# Authentication In Apache Hive

Tags: apache, hive

I have installed apache hive 13.1 in my redhat system.

Hiveserver2 is installed and running and I have connected it through beeline via command below

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://redhat:10000 username password org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

‘username’ and ‘password’ being default username and password respectively.

Through beeline if I give query like `SELECT * FROM TABLE1`, it is showing below error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException Cannot make directory: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hive-root/hive_2014-11-20_11-25-00_148_8959617153046923444-1 (state=42000,code=40000)
```

I think this error is due to the default username which I am using doesn’t have permission to create a directory in HDFS.

So, can anyone please help me to know, how to change the permission of a user and how to create a new user in hiveserver2?

Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We are running hiveserver2 on an AWS EMR cluster and haven't configured any additional authentication.

We had the same error when we did not specify a username and password.  In our case, for AWS EMR without additional configuration we found connecting with username 'hadoop' with no password worked for us.

Comment: Hi Kurt,using hadoop as username and no password doesnt work for me, can u please tell me, how do i create user in hivesever2 or it uses redhat user for login.